# Simple remote data autocomplete with jQuery UI?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Why the following code doesn't work? (if I change remote source there to local, then it works well)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
      source: "http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/search.php",
            minLength: 2,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
            }

    });
  });
  </script>
    <style>
    .ui-autocomplete-loading { background: white url('http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif') right center no-repeat; }
    </style>  
</head>
<body style="font-size:62.5%;">

<input id="autocomplete" />

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

same origin policy as the source requires a script from another site to be run.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

You could change the source to use a jquery ajax call to another site which can return jsonp.

See this for an example: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

or ensure that the source url given returns jsonp.